# Can i remove the default splash screen of someone else project by publishing it using my unity plus?

Tags: unity, legal, splash-screen

If i use my unity plus to remove the default splash screen from someone else project (that person are using free version of unity) , then export the project also using my unity plus , what are the legal concern ?

Comment: Is the game making more than $100k per year for any one of you?

Comment: The person making the game agreed to a TOS that states "you will not remove...any copyright, trademark, service mark...". Even if you do it on their behalf, that would be a breach of the terms to which they agreed.

Comment: Extremely unlikely to be allowed. This is basically reselling/sublicensing Unity Plus.